# CsvHelper - read in multiple columns to a single dictionary

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

In one project, I have to deal with CSV files and since csvHelper library became very popular in Nuget, I wanted to give it a try. But I could not manage to address my need using it yet.

I tried googling and read many different blogs and StackOverflow answers, still, I am unable to solve it.
Think about following classes.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FixedAttributes1{ get; set; }
    public string FixedAttributes2 { get; set; }
    public AttributeDictionary DynamicAttributes{ get; set; }
}

public class AttributeDictionary 
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Attributes{ get; set; }
}
```

I would like to deserialize my csv files into above class model.

```
"FixedAttributes1","FixedAttributes2","DynamicAttr1","DynamicAttr2","DynamicAttr3",...
```

My CSV files have a dynamic number of columns. In each row FixedAttributes1,FixedAttributes2 always exists. Remaining columns are optional. Hence I would like to store those columns as Key/Value pair format in my Dictionary.

Any idea, how I can do this?

Regards

Comment: I'm looking for the solution as well.